# Growth rate of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrences

For a side project with a friend (having to do with fractional iterates of the exponential function), we're looking at a sequence $a_n$ defined recursively by equations $a_1 = 1$ and

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n \brace k} a_k c^{k-1}$$

where ${n \brace k}$ denotes a Stirling number of the second kind, and $c$ is a certain complex number (if you must know, it's $-W_{-1}(-1) \approx 0.318 + 1.337i$, where $W_{-1}$ refers to a branch of the Lambert W function, although I doubt the exact value is so important for the question I have).

I'm interested in the growth rate of $|a_n|$, or some decent upper bounds. Ultimately, my question is whether the function

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k x^k}{k!}$$

has a positive radius of convergence. For example, if $|a_k| = O(\frac{k!}{|c|^k})$, something that seems supported by programs my friend has run up to $k = 2000$, then that would settle the issue.

Any hints about how to perform this sort of asymptotic analysis would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to check: is the sum on the RHS of the recursion going up to $n$ (as written) or up to $n-1$?

Comment: It's going up to $n$, because it looks nicer that way. So it's equivalent to $(1 - c^{n-1})a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n \brace k} a_k c^{k-1}$.